# Tag merge [freeze] - [freezing]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

I'm guessing that there really is no difference between the two...

Comment: We need a synonym setup, tag merge is not needed.

Comment: @Sathya didn't know there was a synonym setup... or are you saying that is what is needed?

Comment: `[freezing]` has [been proposed](http://superuser.com/tags/freeze/synonyms) as a synonym for `[freeze] `- this needs to be be approved. That will take care of auto tag renames @kro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, this is done. You might consider asking in the moderator room so we don't clutter meta up with a bunch of minor retag requests..

Comment: Will post future requests there. I'm using the interesting tab algorithm here which hides requests that are completed, and thought that it was okay given the previous retag requests that exist on meta. But now that we have chat rooms, I'm sorry for the clutter... And, nice to see both you and Diago jump in, thumbs up! +1 :-)